# ffmpeg -i not working when converting media files to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, multimedia, command-line-tool

I'm using FFmpeg to convert my media file because It's a free source. But can't figure out how to use it. It takes one and a half hour just to troubleshoot but I totally messed up! I went here to seek any help (I'm using windows 8.1 OS)

[I configure path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX2kv.png)

[command: ffmpeg -i invalid? why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO2tX.png)

[It seems working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV0M5.png)

[i:no such file or directory?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KtBi.png)

[I even tried New version 2021, but still "Missing argument for option 'i'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/denDt.png)

Comment: Your ffmpeg is 6 years old. Get a new one from www.gyan.dev. Basic command: `ffmpeg -i input.ts output.mp4`

Comment: I even tried the new one version 2021, but still ffmpeg -i input.ts output.mp4 > "missing argument for option 'i'

Comment: Hi, what version of ffmpeg are you using, and which OS (and version)? It's good to always add that info in your questions :)

Comment: @outtobias0x9 You need to show your command and the complete log for the new error. Your latest screenshot does not show the error and I can't see the command you actually executed. Please copy and paste the text instead of making images of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I Didn't specify that I'm using Windows OS (8.1). Anyway, the problem was solved by installing a higher version of .Netframework in my case 4.7.1. For 50 MB ts.file, It will take 5:43.84 minutes until the conversion was done. Thank you community for the support.

[Problem solved !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GANrT.png)